# How does this NOR gate S-R latch work?

Tags: flipflop

I am unclear who the NOR gate S-R latch works.

If the input of one depends on the output of the second one, and vice versa, no output signal can be generated until we have a single gate output.

[image]

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Possibly related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/524618/35022

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the beginning state for Q in a SR latch?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/14653/what-is-the-beginning-state-for-q-in-a-sr-latch)

Answer (score 3):

> if input of one is depandant of output of second **and vice versa**.

It isn't. With the input levels shown, the upper [NAND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_gate) gate's output can be either 1 or 0, but the lower NAND gate's output *must* be 1. That means the upper NAND gate's output *will* be 0.

Where it gets interesting is when both inputs are 1. Then the flip-flop will **hold** whatever state it had when one input was 0.

But what if both inputs are 0? In that case *both* outputs must be 1. Making one input high again would allow the other input to set that state. If both inputs are made high at exactly the same time then the state 'flipped' to will be random.